# Combing aggregate operations in a single result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two aggregate operations that I'd like to combine. The first operation returns, for example:

```
{ "_id" : "Colors", "count" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "Animals", "count" : 6 }
```

and the second operation returns, for example:

```
{ "_id" : "Red", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "Blue", "count" : 9 }
{ "_id" : "Green", "count" : 9 }
{ "_id" : "White", "count" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "Yellow", "count" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "Orange", "count" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "Black", "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "Goose", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "Chicken", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Grey", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Cat", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Rabbit", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Duck", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Turkey", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Elephant", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Shark", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Fish", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Tiger", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Purple", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Pink", "count" : 1 }
```

How do I combine the 2 operations to achieve the following?

```
{ "_id" : "Colors", "count" : 12, "items" :
    [
        { "_id" : "Red", "count" : 10 },
        { "_id" : "Blue", "count" : 9 },
        { "_id" : "Green", "count" : 9 },
        { "_id" : "White", "count" : 7 },
        { "_id" : "Yellow", "count" : 7 },
        { "_id" : "Orange", "count" : 7 },
        { "_id" : "Black", "count" : 5 },
        { "_id" : "Grey", "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "Purple", "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "Pink", "count" : 1 }
    ]
},
{ "_id" : "Animals", "count" : 6, "items" :
    [
        { "_id" : "Goose", "count" : 4 },
        { "_id" : "Chicken", "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "Cat", "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "Rabbit", "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "Duck", "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "Turkey", "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "Elephant", "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "Shark", "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "Fish", "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "Tiger", "count" : 2 }
    ]
}
```

**Schema**

```
var ListSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    items: {
        type: Array,
        default: [String],
        trim: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

**Operation 1**

```
db.lists.aggregate(
      [
        { $group: { _id: "$title", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } }
      ]
    )
```

**Operation 2**

```
db.lists.aggregate(
      [
        { $unwind: "$items" },
        { $group: { _id: "$items", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } }
      ]
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on the kind of results you are after in a respone. The things you are asking about seem to indicate that you are looking for "facet counts" in a result, but I'll touch on that a bit later.

For as basic result, there is nothing wrong with this as an approach:

```js
    Thing.aggregate(
      [
        { "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "type": "$type", "name": "$name"
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id.type",
          "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
          "names": {
            "$push": { "name": "$_id.name", "count": "$count" }
          }
        }}
      ],
      function(err,results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));
        callback(err);
      }
    )
```

Which should give you a result like this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "colours",
    "count": 50102,
    "names": [
      { "name": "Green",  "count": 9906  },
      { "name": "Yellow", "count": 10093 },
      { "name": "Red",    "count": 10083 },
      { "name": "Orange", "count": 9997  },
      { "name": "Blue",   "count": 10023 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "animals",
    "count": 49898,
    "names": [
      { "name": "Tiger",    "count": 9710  },
      { "name": "Lion",     "count": 10058 },
      { "name": "Elephant", "count": 10069 },
      { "name": "Monkey",   "count": 9963  },
      { "name": "Bear",     "count": 10098 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the very basic approach here is to simply [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in two stages, where the first stage aggregates on the combination of keys down to the lowest ( most granular ) grouping level, and then process a `$group` again to basically "add up" the totals on the highest ( least granular ) grouping level, also thus adding the lower results to an array of items.

But this is not "separated" as it would be in "facet counts", so to do this becomes a little more complex, as well as a little more insane. But first the example:

```js
    Thing.aggregate(
      [
        { "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "type": "$type",
            "name": "$name"
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id.type",
          "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
          "names": {
            "$push": { "name": "$_id.name", "count": "$count" }
          }
        }},
        { "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          "types": {
            "$push": {
              "type": "$_id", "count": "$count"
            }
          },
          "names": { "$push": "$names" }
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$names" },
        { "$unwind": "$names" },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$types",
          "names": { "$push": "$names" }
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "_id": 0,
          "facets": {
            "types": "$_id",
            "names": "$names",
          },
          "data": { "$literal": [] }
        }}
      ],
      function(err,results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0], undefined, 2));
        callback(err);
      }
    );
```

Which will produce output like this:

```js
{
  "facets": {
    "types": [
      { "type": "colours", "count": 50102 },
      { "type": "animals", "count": 49898 }
    ],
    "names": [
      { "name": "Green",    "count": 9906  },
      { "name": "Yellow",   "count": 10093 },
      { "name": "Red",      "count": 10083 },
      { "name": "Orange",   "count": 9997  },
      { "name": "Blue",     "count": 10023 },
      { "name": "Tiger",    "count": 9710  },
      { "name": "Lion",     "count": 10058 },
      { "name": "Elephant", "count": 10069 },
      { "name": "Monkey",   "count": 9963  },
      { "name": "Bear",     "count": 10098 }
    ]
  },
  "data": []
}
```

What should be apparent though is while "possible", the kind of "juggling" going on here in the pipeline to produce this output format is not really efficient. Compared to the first example, there is a lot of overhead in here just to simply split out the results into their own array responses and independently of the grouping keys. This notably becomes more complex with the more "facets" to generate.

Also as hinted at here in the output, what people generally ask of "facet counts" is that that the result "data" is also included in the response ( likely paged ) in addition to the aggregated facets. So the further complications should be apparent right here:

```js
        { "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          (...)
```

Where the requirement of this type of operation is to basically "stuff" every piece of data into a single object. In most cases, and certainly where you want the actual data in results ( using 100,000 in this sample ) it becomes completely impractical to follow this approach and will almost certainly exceed the BSON document limit size of 16MB.

In such a case, where you want to produce results and the "facets" of that data in a response, then the best approach here is to run each aggregation and the output page as separate query operations and "stream" the output JSON ( or other format ) back to the receiving client.

As a self contained example:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/things');

var data = {
      "colours": [
        "Red","Blue","Green","Yellow","Orange"
      ],
      "animals": [
        "Lion","Tiger","Bear","Elephant","Monkey"
      ]
    },
    dataKeys = Object.keys(data);

var thingSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String,
  "type": String
});

var Thing = mongoose.model( 'Thing', thingSchema );

var writer = process.stdout;

mongoose.connection.on("open",function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  async.series(
    [
      function(callback) {
        process.stderr.write("removing\n");
        Thing.remove({},callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        process.stderr.write("inserting\n");
        var bulk = Thing.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
            count = 0;

        async.whilst(
          function() { return count < 100000; },
          function(callback) {
            var keyLen    = dataKeys.length,
                keyIndex  = Math.floor(Math.random(keyLen)*keyLen),
                type      = dataKeys[keyIndex],
                types     = data[type],
                typeLen   = types.length,
                nameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random(typeLen)*typeLen),
                name      = types[nameIndex];

            var obj = { "type": type, "name": name };
            bulk.insert(obj);
            count++;

            if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
              process.stderr.write('insert count: ' + count + "\n");
              bulk.execute(function(err,resp) {
                bulk = Thing.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                callback(err);
              });
            } else {
              callback();
            }

          },
          callback
        );
      },

      function(callback) {
        writer.write("{ \n  \"page\": 1,\n  \"pageSize\": 25,\n")
        writer.write("  \"facets\":  {\n");      // open object response

        var stream = Thing.collection.aggregate(
          [
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$name",
              "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }}
          ],
          {
            "cursor": {
              "batchSize": 1000
            }
          }
        );

        var counter = 0;

        stream.on("data",function(data) {
          stream.pause();

          if ( counter == 0 ) {
            writer.write("    \"names\": [\n");
          } else {
            writer.write(",\n");
          }

          data = { "name": data._id, "count": data.count };

          writer.write("      " + JSON.stringify(data));

          counter++;
          stream.resume();
        });

        stream.on("end",function() {
          writer.write("\n    ],\n");

          var stream = Thing.collection.aggregate(
            [
              { "$group": {
                "_id": "$type",
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
              }}
            ],
            {
              "cursor": {
                "batchSize": 1000
              }
            }
          );

          var counter = 0;
          stream.on("data",function(data) {
            stream.pause();

            if ( counter == 0 ) {
              writer.write("    \"types\": [\n");
            } else {
              writer.write(",\n");
            }

            data = { "name": data._id, "count": data.count };

            writer.write("      " + JSON.stringify(data));

            counter++;
            stream.resume();
          });

          stream.on("end",function() {
            writer.write("\n    ]\n  },\n");

            var stream = Thing.find({}).limit(25).stream();
            var counter = 0;

            stream.on("data",function(data) {
              stream.pause();
              if ( counter == 0 ) {
                writer.write("  \"data\": [\n");
              } else {
                writer.write(",\n");
              }

              writer.write("    " + JSON.stringify(data));

              counter++;
              stream.resume();

            });

            stream.on("end",function() {
                writer.write("\n  ]\n}\n");
                callback();
            });

          });

        });
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      process.exit();
    }
  );
});
```

With the output like:

```js
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 25,
  "facets":  {
    "names": [
      {"name":"Red","count":10007},
      {"name":"Tiger","count":10012},
      {"name":"Yellow","count":10119},
      {"name":"Monkey","count":9970},
      {"name":"Elephant","count":10046},
      {"name":"Bear","count":10082},
      {"name":"Orange","count":9982},
      {"name":"Green","count":10005},
      {"name":"Blue","count":9884},
      {"name":"Lion","count":9893}
    ],
    "types": [
      {"name":"colours","count":49997},
      {"name":"animals","count":50003}
    ]
  },
  "data": [
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdcc02","type":"animals","name":"Lion"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc81b","type":"colours","name":"Blue"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc81c","type":"colours","name":"Orange"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc81d","type":"animals","name":"Bear"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc81e","type":"animals","name":"Elephant"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc81f","type":"colours","name":"Orange"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc820","type":"colours","name":"Green"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc821","type":"animals","name":"Lion"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc822","type":"animals","name":"Monkey"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc823","type":"colours","name":"Yellow"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc824","type":"colours","name":"Yellow"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc825","type":"colours","name":"Orange"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc826","type":"animals","name":"Monkey"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc827","type":"colours","name":"Blue"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc828","type":"animals","name":"Tiger"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc829","type":"colours","name":"Red"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82a","type":"animals","name":"Monkey"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82b","type":"animals","name":"Elephant"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82c","type":"animals","name":"Tiger"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82d","type":"animals","name":"Bear"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82e","type":"colours","name":"Yellow"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc82f","type":"animals","name":"Lion"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc830","type":"animals","name":"Elephant"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc831","type":"colours","name":"Orange"},
    {"_id":"55bf141f3edc150b6abdc832","type":"animals","name":"Elephant"}
  ]
}
```

There are some considerations in here, notably that mongoose [`.aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) does not really directly support the standard node stream interface. There is an `.each()` method available from [`.cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor) on an aggregate method, but the "stream" implied from the [core API method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate) gives a lot more control here, so the `.collection` mehod here to get the underlying [driver object](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html) is preferable. Hopefully a future mongoose release will consider this.

So if your end goal is such a "facet count" alongside the results as demonstrated here, then each aggregation and results make the most sense to "stream" in the way as demonstrated. Without that, the aggregation becomes both overcomplicated as well as very likely to exceed the BSON limit, just as doing otherwise in this case would.

Comment: Wow. What a brilliant and thorough answer. Thank you so much.